# Let $R[x,y]$ be a finitely generated $R$-module ($x,y\in S$ where $R\subseteq S$ some subring). Then $xy\in R[x,y]$?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules

I know that $R[x,y]$ contains $x+y$ from its definition as $R$-module, but is $xy\in R[x,y]$ as well?

I am not sure how multiplication works (other than multiplication of $r\in R[x,y]$ by a scalar $a\in R$).

Comment: $R[x,y]$ means the polynomial ring with coeffiicients in $R$ and with variables $x,y$ so $xy$ is indeed in $R[x,y]$.

Comment: as @daruma says, $R[x,y]$ normally denotes the polynomial ring in two variables over $R$, but this is *not* a finitely generated $R$-module. (in fact, it is isomorphic to $R^{\oplus\mathbb{N}}$ as an $R$-module.) could you clarify what you mean by $R[x,y]$? (p.s. I love your profile picture :') )

Comment: @daruma sorry, I forgot to mention that $x,y$ are integral over $R$. And then $R[x,y]$ is a finitely generated R-module.

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to prove that **the sum and product of two integral elements over $R$ are also integral** as Atiyah and Macdonald are doing in Corollary 5.3.

If one reads carefully the Corollary 5.2 can notice that the *ring* $R[x,y]$ is a finitely generated $R$-module, and then $x+y,xy\in R[x,y]$ (the sum and product of two elements of a ring belong to the ring).

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking about $R[x,y]$ for so long as just an $R$-module that I forgot that it's a ring by definition... thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your definition of the polynomial ring there are several ways to see that $R[x,y]$ does indeed contain an element of the name $xy$.

I think the easiest way is by using the definition $R[x,y]= (R[x])[y]$. Clearly the polynomial ring $S[y]$ contains an element of the form $sy$ and substituting $S=R[x]$ we can deduce the existence of $xy$.

If your definition is $R[x,y] = \operatorname{Map}_\text{fin}(\Bbb N \times \Bbb N, R)$ (meaning maps with finite support) with pointwise addition and multiplication given by convolution it is a tiny bit more involved to show that the map
$$\begin{array}{rcl}
\Bbb N \times \Bbb N &\rightarrow &R\\
(1,1) & \mapsto & 1\\
(i,j) & \mapsto & 0
\end{array}$$
represents *the* element $xy$.

Answer (score 1):

Since the polynomial ring in two variables over $R$ is *not* a finitely generated $R$-module, you are apparently talking about something else.

Presumably, $x$ and $y$ are elements of some larger $R$-algebra $S$ and $R[x,y]$ denotes, by definition, the smallest $R$-algebra in $S$ containing $x$ and $y$. So, yes, being an $R$-algebra, this means that $xy \in R[x,y]$.

Note that if $x$ and $y$ are elements of some larger $R$-module $M$, and you want to talk about the smallest $R$-module in $M$ containing $x$ and $y$, you'd write $Rx + Ry$. This does not (necessarily) contain $xy$.